# Unable to start Logstash service on Centos7

Tags: logstash

When i am trying to start the logstash as a service in centos 7 i am getting below error all the time. I am not a great linux guy, so any help with the start-limit error would be a great help. I tried to follow some links to fix or reset the **StartLimitInterval** etc, but in vain.

```
[root@resource-managers logstash-5.1.1]# service logstash status
Logstash Daemon● logstash.service - logstash
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2017-02-01 17:49:11 UTC; 741ms ago
  Process: 8562 ExecStart=/home/centos/logstash-5.1.1/bin/logstash --path.settings /home/centos/logstash-5.1.1/config (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 8562 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: Unit logstash.service entered failed state.
Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: logstash.service failed.
Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: logstash.service holdoff time over, schedulin...rt.
Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for logsta...ice
Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: Failed to start logstash.
Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: Unit logstash.service entered failed state.
Feb 01 17:49:11 resource-managers.cisco.com systemd[1]: logstash.service failed.
```

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same problem, and solved it. Maybe it can help you.

Can you check your `${LS_HOME}/config/startup.options` file? You should set `LC_USER` and `LC_GROUP` to existed account and group .

```
# user and group id to be invoked as
LS_USER=elk-test
LS_GROUP=elk-test
```

In my system, I changed the default value "logstash" to "elk-etst".

After that, ran the system-install command, and started the service, it worked!

```
● logstash.service - logstash
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-02-05 11:10:04 CST; 8s ago
 Main PID: 7395 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/logstash.service
           └─7395 /usr/bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Df...
```

ps: I'm running logstash-5.1.2